Simplifying URLs for PHP Web App in Apache: Removing 'public' Folder and Pages Path
Here is the folder structure of my PHP web app. I use Apache on localhost to run the PHP project. I have two issues:

When I run the project using the URL http://localhost/CALCULATOR/public, I would like to run it using http://localhost/CALCULATOR without needing to include the public folder in the URL. How can I achieve this without changing my current folder structure?

I have 4-5 pages like about-us.php, contact-us.php, etc. Currently, I need to open these pages like this: http://localhost/CALCULATOR/src/pages/about-us.php. I want to access them like this: http://localhost/CALCULATOR/about-us.


How can I solve these issues?
all things try but not working

http://localhost/CALCULATOR/src/pages/about-us.php - to clarify, are these "public" files outside of the /public subdirectory? Are you referencing any static assets (JS, CSS, images)? What URLs are you using for these assets?

first you need to allow .htaccess on apache server.
Open your httpd.conf  with notepad, Which is located in the path \apache\conf directory.
search for the line :

#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Remove # from above code .
search for the line :

AllowOverride

make it  AllowOverride All
Save httpd.conf file and restart your apache server
in .htaccess file write the code below depending on your needs
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^about-us ./src/pages/about-us.php

